# SharePoint -ways to manage content

Tags: sharepoint

a client is requiring an Internet-facing CMS system on MOSS 2007.

I am trying to identify all the possible ways to manage content -this is what I came up with:

1. Web parts through browser.
2. Web parts through Designer.
3. Lists (Columns and Content Types as required).

Is there any other way I am missing?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
This is really a high-level question. What options does SharePoint offer to non-developers, non-designers to edit pages of an Internet-facing, marketing site? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have different content pages in your Pages document libraries.  These pages are not web part pages per se, but rich text area pages.  See the Pages document library in a publishing site.

You can also aggregate content easily using the Content Query Web Part.  This can pool content together from all across your site collection.  I find it very useful to have to configure it to pull all of one content type, so no matter where the content is location in your site, the CQWP will aggregate it to one list.

You could also get more advanced and turn on document conversions.  Have a word document that gets sent to the sharepoint and then it automatically converted to web page. Just one more way to deliver content.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow your question 100%, but FWIW content can be managed programmatically using the [Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473633.aspx) or [Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390(office.12).aspx) API's.
Not to mention WebDav, mail subscriptions etc.

Comment: This is really a high-level question. What options does SharePoint offer to non-developers, non-designers to edit pages of an Internet-facing, marketing site? Thank you.